# XSD schema error, base type is expected to be a complex type, how do I fix?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Not sure what's going on but I get this error when I try to validate my schema:

> complex type 'Tnamedefinition': If using , the base type is expected to be a complex type. The base type '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string' is a simple type.

Here's my xml file:

```
<league year="2014" source="www.ico.org"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="champions.xsd">
    <sources>
        <source metalane="top">
                    <champion name="wukong">
                            <popularity>8.18</popularity>
                            <banrate>0.51</banrate>
                    </champion>
                    <champion name="renekton">          
                            <popularity>24.26</popularity>
                            <banrate>8.69</banrate>
                    </champion>
                    <champion name="riven">
                            <popularity>11.75</popularity>
                            <banrate>12.85</banrate>
                    </champion>     
                    <champion name="drmundo">
                            <popularity>12.11</popularity>
                            <banrate>64.46</banrate>
                    </champion>     
        </source>

        <source metalane="mid">
                <champion name="ziggs">
                        <popularity>15.09</popularity>
                        <banrate>20.56</banrate>
                </champion>     
                <champion name="gragas">
                        <popularity>22.45</popularity>
                        <banrate>25.89</banrate>
                </champion>
                <champion name="kayle">
                        <popularity>13.63</popularity>
                        <banrate>9.37</banrate>
                </champion>
                <champion name="khazix">
                        <popularity>21.71</popularity>
                        <banrate>37.28</banrate>
                </champion>         
        </source>

        <source metalane="marksman">
                <champion name="lucian">
                        <popularity>18.95</popularity>
                        <banrate>1.18</banrate>
                </champion>     
                <champion name="ezreal">
                        <popularity>21.26</popularity>
                        <banrate>0.11</banrate>
                </champion>
                <champion name="draven">
                        <popularity>15.88</popularity>
                        <banrate>5.85</banrate>
                </champion>
                <champion name="jinx">
                        <popularity>34.82</popularity>
                        <banrate>4.98</banrate>
                </champion>     
        </source>
    </sources>
</league>
```

And here's my xsd schema file:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!-- A year is a 4-digit integer, except the year must be >= 1998. -->
    <xs:simpleType name="Tyear">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{4}"/>
            <xs:minInclusive value="1998"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- A lane is a string which specifies which location on the map a champion goes -->
    <xs:simpleType name="Tmetalane">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">

        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- A name is a string which specifies a champions name -->
    <xs:simpleType name="Tname">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">

        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Tperc">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">    
            <xs:minExclusive value="0.0"/>
            <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>    
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- A definition associates a metalane with a value.  -->
    <xs:complexType name="Tdefinition">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="metalane" type="Tmetalane"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- A name definition associates a champion with a value.  -->
    <xs:complexType name="Tnamedefinition">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="Tname"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>


    <!-- league
    The root element is *league*.
    It contains a sources element which contains multiple source elements.
    -->
    <xs:element name="league">        
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="sources" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="year" type="Tyear"/>
            <xs:attribute name="source" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- sources
    The *sources* element defines multiple metalanes which
    contain champion information regarding that lane.
    -->
    <xs:element name="sources">        
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="source" type="Tdefinition" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="metalanes">
            <xs:selector xpath="source"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@metalane"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- source
    The *source* element contains multiple champion elements
    -->
    <xs:element name="source">        
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="champion" type="Tnamedefinition" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- champion
    The *champion* element contains a banrate and popularity element
    -->
    <xs:element name="champion">        
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="popularity"/>        
                <xs:element ref="banrate"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="Tname"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- A *popularity* element defines how often a champion is picked  -->
    <xs:element name="popularity">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="Tperc">
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- A *banrate* element defines how often a champion is banned  -->
    <xs:element name="banrate">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="Tperc">
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `<complexContent>`. You can't use a simple type (`xs:string`) as a base type for an extension. It must be a complex type.

You have `<champion>` defined as a top-level element with an anonymous nested complex-type, and then again inside `<source>` as a `Tnamedefinition`. From your XML source I believe you should actually declare a reference to the top-level `champion` and remove the `type` declaration:

```
<xs:element name="source">        
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="champion" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And then you can remove the type declaration for `Tnamedefinition`, which is causing the error.

You have the same problem in `<sources>` which won't validate your document because you declared it as empty.

```
<xs:element name="sources">        
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="source" type="Tdefinition" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

...

And `Tdefinition` is a complex type with simple content which only allows an attribute. You can move the attribute declaration to the complex type in the `<source>` element definition:

```
<xs:element name="source">        
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="champion" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="metalane" type="Tmetalane" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

You also don't need `Tdefinition` and should declare `source` as a reference to the top-level element.

```
<xs:element name="sources">        
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="source" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    ...
</xs:element>
```

With these changes, the document will validate. But you also have a bunch of unused type declarations which, unless your other XML instances are very different from the one you show here, you probably won't use and can remove. For example, unless `popularity` and `banrate` have attributes, you can declare them as simple types:

```
<xs:element name="popularity" type="Tperc"/>
<xs:element name="banrate" type="Tperc"/>
```

Since you don't use them anywhere else, you could also nest them in the `champion` definition.

I assume that `Tmetalane` and `Tname` are types you still are working on (since the restrictions are in place but empty).

Making the changes and removing the unused types, the resulting schema is as follows:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="Tyear">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{4}"/>
            <xs:minInclusive value="1998"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Tmetalane">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <!-- to be added  -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Tname">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <!-- to be added -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Tperc">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">    
            <xs:minExclusive value="0.0"/>
            <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>    
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="league">        
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="sources" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="year" type="Tyear"/>
            <xs:attribute name="source" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="sources">        
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="source" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="metalanes">
            <xs:selector xpath="source"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@metalane"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="source">        
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="champion" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="metalane" type="Tmetalane" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="champion">        
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="popularity" type="Tperc"/>
                <xs:element name="banrate" type="Tperc"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="Tname"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Seems to involve a far more radical change than is actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the message from Saxon for comparison:

```
Error on line 44 of test.xsd:
  The type Tnamedefinition has complex content so it cannot be based on the simple type xs:string
```

What you *can* define by extension from xs:string is a "complex type with simple content" (that is, an element with attributes but no child elements). That's achieved simply by changing "complexContent" to "simpleContent".